# WP Business Directory Manager Plugin Admin Listings?

Tags: php

I'm using the WP Business Directory Manager plugin and I'm having some problems. I've been meaning, as an admin, to add a Listing to my directory, but it shows pended, so i look a round the plugin a found a way to change it in the backoffice but it published every listings. Is there a way to have only the admin that his listings get published by default?

In the `listing.php`:

```
 if ( !$data->listing_id && ( !$listing_cost || current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) ) {
         wp_update_post( array( 'ID' => $listing_id, 'post_status' => wpbdp_get_option( 'new- post-status' ) ) );
 }
```

the setting of the `new-post-status`:

```
$this->add_setting($s, 'new-post-status', _x('Default new post status', 'admin settings', 'WPBDM'), 'choice', 'pending', '',
                       array('choices' => array('publish', 'pending'))
                       );
```

Much appreciated.

Comment: I was thinking to add a status like `admin_publish` that checks if the user is an admin then it published it listings without getting pended else the listings get pended. I just need some assistance on how I could do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test by the admin login name:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$my_user = $current_user->user_login;
if (strpos($my_user,'admin') !== false) { // test for the admin username

if ( !$data->listing_id && ( !$listing_cost || current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) ) {
    wp_update_post( array( 'ID' => $listing_id, 'post_status' => 'publish' ) ); //update post to publish
        }       
}else{
   if ( !$data->listing_id && ( !$listing_cost || current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) ) {
    wp_update_post( array( 'ID' => $listing_id, 'post_status' => wpbdp_get_option( 'new-post-status' ) ) ); //let the post in "pendin" position
}
}
```

Hope this would workout for you.